# Not able to start Sitecore Indexing Manager

Tags: sitecore, azure-cognitive-search, sitecore9

I want to configure Azure Search instead of the default Solr search engine in Sitecore 9.2 as PaaS. I am getting following exception while accessing the Sitecore Indexing Manager:

> Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchDocumentBuilderOptions,Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure (method: Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).

I have verified the entry in `ConnectionStrings.config` and also the `showconfig`.

Comment: Bruce from the Azure Search team here. We're unable to help with the diagnosis as this looks like an error on the Sitecore side. Your best bet might be to go to https://support.sitecore.net/ for help.

Answer (score 1):

**Earlier we have to add these settings for Habitat Sitecore Content Search –**

Class File -

Sitecore.Foundation.Indexing.Infrastructure.Fields.AllTemplatesComputedField, Sitecore.Foundation.Indexing

Settings in Config -

```
<field fieldName="all_templates" storageType="no" indexType="untokenized">Sitecore.Foundation.Indexing.Infrastructure.Fields.AllTemplatesComputedField, Sitecore.Foundation.Indexing</field>
```

**To resolve the issue:**

We have to remove both the class and config settings and enable which is recommended below.

Check the latest installation folder 9.x.x. folder you will find “Example” folder “App_Config\Include\Examples” they have provided new config file called “Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.DefaultIndexConfiguration.AllTemplates.config.example”

We just have to activate above config to resolve the issue.

After that Azure Search will work and all the search fields will be appearing on Sitecore.